# Opening a div (a box with a list of links) after click of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i display a box at the side of a button after a click?

**HTML**

---

```
<button><a href="#">Open box at side</a></button>
<div id="link-box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

---

```
#link-box {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#link-box ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWkHY.png)

Comment: html + javascript + css would be the standard way

Comment: @JaromandaX I am new in html i'm just using my friends account here in stackoverflow. Can you help me?

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you need to show what u have tried

Comment: @Hash already edited thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure `CSS` way.

Click on `Button` to Show and `ANYWHERE` to DISMISS.

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

button.toggle {
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#link-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.toggle:focus~#link-box {
 display: block;
}

#link-box > ul > li {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 10px;
}

#link-box > ul > li > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle">Button</button>
  <div id="link-box">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.d{
    border:4px solid black;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}

.d1{
    border:4px solid black;
    width:100px;
    float:left
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="d">
<button>Button</button>
</div>
<div class="d1" >
<a href="#">link1</a><br>
<a href="#">link2</a><br>
<a href="#">link3</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>


[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: i want to display the links with its container after i click the button. How di i do it?

Comment: you have to use java script

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #myDIV {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 50px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: lightblue;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>



    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <div id="myDIV">

      <a href="#" > item1 </a><br>
       <a href="#" > item2 </a>

    </datalist> 


    </div>


    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

also see this link with try to paste above code 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Answer (score 0):

> `addClass`, button open `div` only :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#link-box').addClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
#link-box {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><a href="#">Open box at side</a></button>
<div id="link-box">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> `toggleClass`, button open(first click) and close(second click) `div` :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#link-box').toggleClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
#link-box {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }

div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button><a href="#">Open box at side</a></button>
<div id="link-box">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> `slideUp` or `slideDown` or `slideToggle`, runs slowly :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#link-box').slideToggle(1000);
  })
})
```

```css
#link-box {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<button><a href="#">Open box at side</button>
<div id="link-box">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Code with more css:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#link-box').slideToggle(1000);
  })
})
```

```css
#link-box {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 6px;
}

li:hover  {
  background-color: #FFF;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<button><a href="#">Open box at side</a></button>
<div id="link-box">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *JavaScript*,

```js
  
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('#link-box').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#link-box {
  background: #0099cc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Open box at side</button>
  <div id="link-box">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('#link-box').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#link-box {
  background: #0099cc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Open box at side</button>
  <div id="link-box">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```